# Defaultl ACPI sleep state in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, power-management, suspend, acpi

As stated in the ACPI specification and also [here](https://metebalci.com/blog/a-minimum-complete-tutorial-of-cpu-power-management-c-states-and-p-states/) , the sleep states (a.k.a G1 states) of the ACPI is as follows :

> G1/S1: Power on Suspend. The system state is preserved, so CPU and CPU Caches are still powered.
>       G1/S2: CPU is powered off. So CPU and CPU Caches are lost.
>       G1/S3: Standby, Sleep or Suspend to RAM (STR). System RAM remains powered. 
>       G1/S4: Hibernation or Suspend to Disk. Everthing is saved to non-volatile memory (like disk), so RAM and possibly all the system is powered off.

I want to know which one is the default suspend mode in the linux kernel ?

I've noticed that when I suspend my system , some programs like Telegram are still working in the background. I tried instructions [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.rst) to debug my suspends and it was successfull. So is that normal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "programs are still working in the background"? Does that mean that suspend isn't actually working for you? (I know it isn't for me). Anyway you can find more here, if this is still relevant: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html